# Avoid that Ctrl-C disables input printing

Tags: bash

On one of our servers, whenever I kill a process with `Ctrl-C` (e.g. to terminate a `tail -f` process), my input to bash is not printed anymore. I can blindly type `reset`, which solved the situation, but it is very inconvenient.

I would like that killing a process with `Ctrl-C` would not cause this problem. Do you have any hints?

EDIT: some more information, as requested

The server is running Suse enterprise, with the kernel 2.6.32.
The bash version we have installed is

```
GNU bash, version 3.2.51(1)-release (x86_64-suse-linux-gnu)
```

Concerning tail, it is

```
tail (GNU coreutils) 6.12
```

My current terminal emulator is konsole, but the same happened with a number of other emulators, including GNOME terminal and terminator.

Comment: That is not normal behavior. Please [edit] your question and include any information that might help. For example: what is your OS? What is your terminal emulator? Does this only happen to you or does it affect all users of the machine? Does it only happen when running bash or with all shells?

Comment: @terdon: Actually I've had this with some programs and scripts during repository conversion preparations and it was quite consistent. I think some programs simply do not clean up as needed at Ctrl+C.

Comment: @0xC0000022L OK, but `tail -f`? I, at least, have never had an issue with that.

Comment: @terdon: yeah, never had it with `tail`.

Comment: Um, I doubt this is the issue but please, please update your bash version. That one is still vulnerable to all sorts o security issues, including the recent [shellshock vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellshock_%28software_bug%29). Also, please clarify whether this happens with _all_ programs or only some and tell us if this is only for your user or all.

Comment: Thanks for the comment on security. But I'm just a user of this system, not an administrator. However, the system is not even accessible from the internet.
No, the issue does not happen with all programs, only with some programs. Even with `tail`, it does not always happen, only most of the time.

Comment: How are you connecting to that server? Over SSH? Or are you logged in locally? What's the value of `$TERM`?

Comment: I log in using SSH. My TERM is `screen-256color`. I'm usually inside a tmux session, but the problem happens outside of tmux as well.

Comment: Are you tailing something that is displaying control characters (echo off) ?

Comment: No, it is just plain ASCII printable text.

Answer (score 0):

Normally this only happens when you kill a program that had changed the TTY settings to turn off echo.  e.g. mplayer / mpv, or a text editor.  And even then, most well-behaved programs that modify the TTY catch signals, and put them back to how they found them before exitting from a SIGINT.

It's completely bizarre that you're seeing this kind of behaviour from `tail`.  What happens if you type while tail is running?  You should see echo, with the same kernel-provided line-editting that you get with `cat > /dev/null`.

Maybe you have something else running in the background that is messing with your TTY?  Run `tty` to find out what tty you're on, then you can `stty -a < /dev/that_tty` from another shell to examine the state.  (look for `echo`, rather than `-echo`).